# .txt File passed into ifstream turns contained data into garbage characters?

Tags: c++, pointers, filestream, ifstream

I'm trying to make a simple program for a comp sci class that goes through a list of data in a text file, and assigns it to two different arrays using pointer notation, but I'm running into an issue where the file I'm reading will be corrupted after running the program, but even when the program is terminated and restarted, it seems to still understand the data even though it only shows up as junk unicode/japanese characters when I open it up in a text reader like notepad after the fact? I'm not sure if this is an issue with my IDE or not, as I don't have any declarations to output to the file after it's read.

Here's what the text file looks like before running the program: https://pastebin.com/raw/JYww96RV

This is what it looks like after being ran: https://pastebin.com/raw/yLzDaAtj

This is what I have for code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int readFile(int* &id, int* &group);
void sortArrays (int *userDataArray, int *identifierDataArray, int arraySize);
int binarySearch (int *userDataArray, int *identifierDataArray, int arraySize, int searchValue);

int main()
{
    int *ids;
    int *groups;
    int sizes;


    sizes = readFile(ids, groups);

    for (int i = 0; i < sizes; i++)
    {
        cout << *(groups + i) << " " << *(ids + i) << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;

    delete[] ids;
    delete[] groups;

    return 0;
}
```

```
int readFile(int* &id, int* &group)
{
    ifstream userData; // We're going to start by declaring our data stream 'userData'
    userData.open("data.txt"); // Our data stream is now going to open and associate itself with the 'data.txt' file
    if (!userData) // This is a simple check if the file was properly found, if it wasn't, the error message below will be displayed
    {
        cout << "Error reading file! Make sure your data file is named 'data.txt'";
        exit(1);
    }

    int sizes;
    userData >> sizes;

    id = new int[sizes];
    group = new int[sizes];

    for (int i = 0; i < sizes; i++) userData >> *(id + i) >> *(group + i);

    userData.close();
    return sizes;
}
```

I apologize if I didn't do a justice to explaining this problem properly, but I'm a little bit stuck on where to go from here or how to properly find a fix online as I'm new to the language

Comment: Note that `*(id + i)` is usually written `id[i]`.

Comment: Get in the habit of initializing objects with meaningful values rather than default-initializing them and immediately overwriting the default values. In this case that means changing `ifstream userData; userData.open("data.txt");` to `ifstream userData("data.txt");`. Also, you don't need to call `userData.close();`. The destructor will do that.

Comment: Went ahead and changed the notation back to array notation, but I'm unfortunately still running into the same problem :/

Comment: Note, also, that `exit(1);` is not portable. There are three portable values that you can use here: `EXIT_SUCCESS`, `EXIT_FAILURE`, and `0` (which means the same thing as `EXIT_SUCCESS`).

Comment: Re: "find a fix online" -- find a good textbook.

Comment: Is the problem here that the **input** file gets changed when the program runs? If so, that's got nothing to do with the code shown here.

Comment: Yes, the file that I'm passing in becomes damaged after running the program, what would the cause of that be then?

Comment: How exactly are you executing the program?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the file before & after with a hex editor? As has been commented this makes no sense - something else is going on. I am speculating that the data file in question is not corrupted and is unchanged. Instead, that however you are viewing the file, it is being interpreted as being in a different encoding in the two cases. This is supported by your comment that  your program "seems to still understand the data". A hex editor will show actual binary contents of the file. If it is the same, your question becomes: Why has my file viewer switched the encoding it is using?

Comment: Actually Avi, you're completely correct. For whatever reason, the default windows notepad seemed to go from reading in UTF-8, to UTF-16 LE after running the program, and opening the file in visual studio code shows the data has been untouched. Thank you for your input!

Comment: Use `std::vector` and you won't have to mess with dynamic allocation, `new` and `delete`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like it wasn't an issue with the code at all, but an issue with how windows notepad would first read the file in UTF-8, and after running the program, would switch over to UTF-16 LE as Avi alluded to in the comments.